# Map and reduce functions in CouchDB-Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-python

How is it possible to use map and reduce functions in CouchDB-Python, because the below code does not return anything?

Is it also possible to disable reduce function if it is not needed?

```
import couchdb

# $ sudo systemctl start couchdb
# http://localhost:5984/_utils/


def fill_data(users_no):
    for i in range(users_no):
        doc = {
            '_id': str(i),
            'uname': "name_" + str(i),
        }
        db.save(doc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = couchdb.Server()
    db = server.create("test-pagination")
    fill_data(300)



    map_fun = """
                function(doc) {
                    emit(doc.uname, 1);
                }
              """
    reduce_fun ="_count"


    design = { 'views': {
              'get_unames': {
                  'map': map_fun,
                  'reduce': reduce_fun
                }
            } }
    db["_design/users"] = design

    uname_list = db.view('users/get_unames')

    print uname_list
    for r in uname_list :
        print r.key
```

Comment: It is just a test, right? You are aware that you are not supposed to create the view every time you query it, aren't you? Or you will lose the efficiency benefits of Map/Reduce.

Comment: Your example is weird... If you really want *all the data*, without *custom sorting*, nor *grouping*. You should use query `_all_docs` instead of your custom view. You can even query `_all_docs?include_docs=true` to get documents details. If I may give you an advice: you should explore the HTTP API (and common Map/Reduce algorithms) *before* learning CouchDB-Python.

Answer (score 1):

You give very few details about what you want to get. But I infer from the code that you want **unique names**. If it is so, you definitely need data to be reduced.

Your problem is that you **group** data too much. You should call the view with `group_level=exact` (or `group=true` which is a synonym).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to disable the reduce, and this is exactly what you need:

```
db.view('users/get_unames', reduce=False)
```

With the reduce active, you get exactly one row back, with just a value (300, the count of your rows) and and empty key.